# Como lidar com a pressão dos "colegas"?

Tags: debate

Achei interessante aqui pois estava lembrando numa conversa no chat que existe  uma medalha que, quando você toma três votos negativos e você remove essa pergunta, você ganha a "pressão dos colegas".

Interessante  é que estou pensando em remover realmente essa pergunta (assim que ela for desbloqueada)

[Como remover um atributo CSS com jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110162/como-remover-um-atributo-css-com-jquery)

Recebi um -4 (merecido ou não, já não sei, cada um tem um critério aqui, então temos que respeitar).

O curioso isso tudo é que "colegas" ficará apenas entre áspas, já que os votos negativos não apresentam, de forma alguma, uma maneira de o usuário melhorar a questão.

Foi necessário bloquear a pergunta para que as coisas não piorassem.

Alguns me aconselharam a não remover a pergunta, mas me pergunto como  uma pergunta com tantos votos negativos pode merecer credibilidade? Se os votos negativos realmente significam isso, pois ultimamente, eles têm parecido não significar  nada...

E eu não fiz essa publicação esperando ser bem recebido, rsrsrsrsrsrs.

Comment: Os votos negativos podem ser usados para apontar uma pergunta de baixa qualidade, assim a pergunta ira para fila de analise, contudo, nada impede que usuários mal intencionados use esta ferramenta para outra finalidade, que é o que parece estar acontecendo no seu caso, sendo assim, uma pergunta boa não vai deixar de ser boa por sofrer vários votos negativos em pouco tempo, por isso sugiro não remover a pergunta, já que a mesma já possui respostas que podem ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: -1, não concordo em você remover a pergunta. Já passei por essa dúvida e, apesar dos negativos, acho que ela pode ser útil futuramente, ;)

Comment: Não removas a pergunta. E porque foi bloqueada?

Comment: @Earendul não acha que os negativos "manchem" a pergunta, ainda que esteja bem feita?

Comment: Alias, vi agora que você já tem essa medalha, será que ela é ganha por pergunta, ou só uma vez?

Comment: Não sei, na verdade, foi um pretexto pra fazer essa pergunta, rsrsrsrs

Comment: +1 já chega de andarem a atazanar o Wallace.

Comment: @JorgeB. e olha que eu tinha feito um "jejum" de perguntas, e mesmo assim...

Comment: uahsuash, eu solicitei 3 votos negativos, para poder ganhar essa medalha '-'

Comment: Isso me fez fazer essa pergunta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4799/14674

Comment: Acho que uma pergunta **não devia ser negativada** apenas porque [foi feita por um utilizador com reputação elevada](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2170/2541) e cuja resposta é facilmente encontrada com um pequeno esforço de pesquisa

Comment: O que pode acontecer é ela ser mal entendida e ser considerada por alguns como oportunista.

Comment: @ramaral eu estou já cheio de ouvir esse papo "Pergunta oportunista". Isso dá a impressão que, se um usuário desconfiar dos seus motivos, ele pode negativar sua pergunta. Sendo assim, esse não é um critério que pareça ser justo.

Comment: Se leu o meu comentário anterior verá que eu não acho que seja oportunista. Apenas sei que há quem ache.

Comment: Não, eu entendi @ramaral. Eu estou falando que já ouvi várias pessoas falando isso: Que algumas pessoas podem votar negativo por parecer oportunista. Me desculpa se me expressei mal.

Comment: Talvez seja também por causa desse meu jeito de falar, né, kkkkkkkk, que chove -1

Comment: É o problema do texto não incluir o tom em que as palavras são ditas. Por vezes fico na dúvida se os meus comentários não são erradamente entendidos.

Comment: Por isso que a pessoa deveria procurar interpretar boa intenção antes de mais nada. Eu sei que meu estilo faz muita gente achar que sou mal intencionado. Não posso fazer nada quanto a isto. Alguém pode dizer que eu posso mudar meu estilo. Espere sentado :D :D :D Viu como este é o meu estilo? É muito chato ser politicamente correto!

Comment: Eu estava no tópico no momento dos negativos, mas isso não significa que fui eu. Rsrs. Sei que fui um atrás do outro e foi emocionante ver um combo de downvotes. Por isso eu fiquei narrando nos comentários aqueles soco na boca. Esse negócio de reputação, votos só dá discussão. Tem usuário que se preocupa muito com reputação, votos, medalhas. Bobeira, um dia todo mundo morre ou esse site cai, esses pontos vão para o limbo, igual o Yahoo Respostas. Pra mim, votos deveriam ser creditados ou debitados da pergunta e não do usuário. Mimimi abaixo...

Comment: @Zoom Não concordo, os votos e a reputação são importantes, devemos é usá-los correctamente. Como são valiosos sou moderado(criterioso) a dá-los. Em relação aos votos recebidos o melhor é não valorizar os injustamente recebidos.

Comment: @ramaral, pergunta oportunista é esta aqui no Meta que fez o placar no site principal disparar pra +10/-5, jejeje (:e deixo aqui meu Meta +1 pro Wallace como forma de protesto:)

Comment: @ramaral não disse que não é importante, mas seria interessante o sistema de votos ser direcionado para as perguntas e respostas ao invés de ao usuário. Esteticamente não mudaria nada no site. Eu olharia uma pergunta com 15 votos e entenderia que aquela pergunta foi encarada como Boa por 15 usuários. Isso acabaria com aquela história do motivo do voto negativo: votou porquê tem algo errado na pergunta ou resposta ou é pesoal com o AP ou AR ? O voto negativo sempre seria para a pergunta ou resposta e nunca para o Autor. Assim o **bigown** parava de reclamar toda vez que toma um voto negativo.

Comment: @brasofilo *The Meta effect* :) Passa-se de um extremo ao outro. Não sei o que é pior: cascata de negativos ou cascata de positivos.

Comment: @Zoom considerando que responder alguma coisa leva tempo (e o sistema sendo de reputação, tendo votos negativos será ignorada a mesma), o bigown reclama com razão. O problema não é os negativos injustos nesse caso, e sim o efeito que eles causam. A pergunta com negativos é sim mal vista (pois o sistema é de reputação).

Comment: @brasofilo de alguma forma o "efeito meta" deve matar de raiva os haters que estão presentes aqui no comunidade. Se a pergunta tá ruim, sapeca negativo. Se é duplicada, marca. Se é boa, valorize!

Comment: Outro problema que vejo dos negativos injustos: Se um usuário novato ver que fiz uma pergunta "simples" como a que fiz ver que tomou -4 (como era o caso inicial), vai ficar desencorajado de perguntar. Sem contar que as vezes alguns "colegas" são rudes nos comentários com usuários que acabaram de chegar no so - usuários esses que deveriam ser bem recebidos.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters retira o sistema de reputação dos usuários, vamos ver se as respostas continuam sendo as mesmas. Se o benefício é o melhor pra comunidade, as respostas continuarão com a mesma qualidade.

Comment: @Zoom  o sistema deve ser de reputação por algum motivo. Quanto a isso, se eu não quisesse um sistema de reputação, eu teria que me retirar do SO. Mas acho que a reputação tem como objetivo (apenas tem como objetivo mesmo, hehehehe) qualificar uma pergunta como boa ou ruim.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters concordo com você quando fala que os usuários novos são tratados de maneira rude. Hoje mesmo já vi um caso. Eu já falei isso e falo de novo, tem que parar de falar dos usuários no chat. Um usuário posta a pergunta, daí alguém com mais reputação chega no chat, posta a pergunta do usuário lá e fala algo do usuário, não da pergunta... enfim, só gera votos negativos. Vou te falar que sou çanto ? Não sou. Já votei negativo sem motivo, aliás, tinha um motivo: quanto mais o usuário reclamava de votos negativos, mais eu votava negativo. Mas é só. Eu sabia que ia ser revertido.

Comment: Hum... temos uma delação premiada aqui :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters e engrandecer o usuário.

Comment: @Zoom bem, nem sempre acho que esses votos são facilmente revertidos.  Eu acho que no geral não são só os downvotes que estão prejudicando. Esses comportamentos no geral também.

Comment: Não lembro qual foi o comentário, mas teve um que deu um `turn down for what`, que, se eu fosse o usuário novato, não voltaria a perguntar mais nada aqui.

Comment: Por que está falando mal de mim no chat @WallaceMaxters ? :(

Comment: @Zoom to não, meu filho. Eu achei o comentário engraçado, só isso mesmo.

Comment: Desculpe, cheguei agora... o quê estamos debatendo nessa pergunta?

Comment: @EMBarbosa sei lá. Mas toma aqui uma pipoca e senta no sofá, parece que o filme é bom.

Comment: A pergunta do @EMBarbosa é pertinente... Acho que há um debate muito bom escondido em algum lugar aqui, mas a gente ainda não encontrou...

Answer (score 1):

Eu lidaria da seguinte maneira:

1. Usuários apontaram o motivo dos votos negativos?
   1.1 Se sim, esses motivos realmente são justos?
   1.1.1 Se sim, eu edito a minha pergunta e faço as "correções"
   1.1.2 Se não, eu mantenho minha pergunta do jeito que está. Eventualmente pessoas com um melhor bom senso verão que não há erros e tentarão elevar a reputação da pergunta... ou não...
   1.2 Se não, faço o mesmo do item 1.1.2

Eu fiz uma pergunta recentemente que recebeu votos negativos, mas ninguém comentou apontando os erros... por isso eu simplesmente ignorei.

Caso a quantidade de votos negativos seja absurda e esteja impactando significativamente minha reputação (esse impacto significativo é relativo para cada pessoa), eu sinalizaria a questão chamando atenção da moderação, caso isso não resolva, eu removeria a questão.