# Medalha Pressão dos Colegas

Tags: debate, medalhas

Estou fazendo essa pergunta com base nesta [Como lidar com a pressão dos "colegas"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4798/14674).

Fico pensando, a medalha [Pressão dos Colegas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure)  **não seria um incentivo para as pessoas propositalmente criarem perguntas ruins com o único objetivo de ganhar a medalha?**

Imagina se todos usuários iriam atrás dela e começassem a postar perguntas sem sentido.

Eu mesmo já quis fazer uma pergunta ruim só para ganhar a medalha, mas não vi sentido em criar uma pergunta só para apagar mais tarde.

Comment: Acho que é só uma vez também.Se o cara remover muitas perguntas, fiquei sabendo que ele é bloqueado. Então não há vantagens :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, acho que sim, senão ia chover perguntas ruins para ganhar a medalha 'várias vezes', :D

Comment: Eu realizei um resposta e ganhei -1, ai solicitei mais "-2" para fechar os -3. Mas nunca pensei nessa possibilidade.

Comment: Já foi discutido no MSE e a conclusão é mais ou menos essa. Não sei se chega causar mais problemas no site que outras coisas e duvido que seja algo para se orgulhar.

Comment: Eu já pedi para votarem negativo em uma resposta minha para eu poder excluir e ganhar a medalha. Fiz isso por bobeira... já tava na roça a resposta mesmo.

Comment: Já ganhei essa medalha por que depois de um tempo eu voltei a olhar as perguntas que eu fiz para tentar melhora-las e reparei em uma pergunta minha que não tinha tanto contexo para o site e negativada, então resolvi remove-la por que achava que ela não tinha qualidade e não para ganhar medalha, até por que, o nome dela não é legal hsuashas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem umas mil variáveis nessa situação toda... Eis o que eu acho:

Você mesmo admitiu que já pensou na possibilidade de criar algo ruim só pra ganhar a medalha, mas desistiu por achar que não valia a pena. Então a medalha não é tããão atraente assim. E você não é o único:

No total, já tivemos posts de uns 13800 usuários diferentes até hoje e a medalha foi concedida 282 vezes, o que dá uns 2%. Mesmo que **todas** tenham sido feitas de propósito (o que obviamente não é verdade), a medalha ainda só causaria 2% de todos os usuários a criarem um conteúdo ruim pra ganhar a medalha.

Além disso, eles teriam criado 282 posts *propositadamente* ruins, dentro dos mais de 101mil que já foram criados até hoje, o que dá 0.2% do conteúdo já feito. E isso, lembrando, considerando que **todas** as medalhas foram recebidas de propósito, o que certamente não é verdade.

Eu não estou dizendo que nunca houve nenhuma situação assim, os próprios comentários aqui admitem casos "semi-intencionais", mas eu não acho - e os números não mostram - que a medalha seja atraente o suficiente para conseguir causar qualquer tipo de dano à saúde da comunidade.

No final das contas, o mundo (e o site) não está repleto de espertalhões doidos pra tirar vantagem à qualquer momento. Se nós trabalharmos para constantemente melhorar a qualidade do SOpt, não há nada que um grupo de "malandros" pode fazer para tirar vantagem do sistema, ou estragar o site.

O outro lado desse negócio todo, levantado em parte pelos comentários, é o quanto nosso chat vem conversando abertamente sobre votos, posts e usuários. Não sei se passamos da conta, e nem cabe a mim decidir isso. Mas acho que a comunidade poderia ter uma conversa sobre o quanto o chat pode influenciar no resultado de alguns posts - para bem e para o mal - e agir como um facilitador de situações desconfortáveis para outros usuários. Ou que até mesmo pareçam contra as regras do site.

Acho que é uma discussão que vale a pena.

Comment: É muita perda de tempo o cara criar uma pergunta errada propositalmente só pra deletar depois e ganhar uma medalha de bronze... Se ela fosse de ouro... (o_O)